# PHP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, php

How will I configure my PHP and MySQL so that they can work with Apache server?
The versions that I use are 
PHP 5.2.9
MySQL 6.0.8
Apache 2.2
I know that I have to configure the php.ini file. But what changes am I supposed to make?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only need this for testing there are a couple of ready to use lampp, xampp stacks out there http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: No. I need them for installing Moodle server. So I can't use xampp or any other thing.

Comment: In future please make the title of your question more informative, thanks!

Comment: FYI: MySQL doesn't have anything to do with Apache so you don't have to do any special configuration magic for them to work together.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know which OS you're using.

1. You might want to install Apache first.
2. When installing PHP, make sure you also install the "mysql" extension (and/or "mysqli").
3. The PHP installer may ask you which server you're running -- select Apache 2.2.x
4. The installer will add the appropriate settings to php.ini for you

Again, the above is assuming you're on Windows, and the installation varies on other OS'es. For example, on Ubuntu you'll likely have to "apt-get" the mysql extension.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, but this will install it for you in 1 click
http://bitnami.org/stack/moodle

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not an answer but google up such phrase "apache mysql php", optionally you can give platform on which you setup webserver. You should have solution in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ready to use and detailed description on how to intall WAMP: "How to Install WAMP"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/installing-php-and-mysql.aspx

Also there are a prebuilt stacks as the commentor above mentioned, XAMPP, etc.

As for the ini...

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5268948.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can just take the installers and install them. That's it.

Everything works out of box

Answer (score 0):

Read PHP's [`install.txt`](http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/win32/install.txt?revision=1.34.2.1.2.3&view=markup&pathrev=php_5_2_9). All the information to configure Apache correctly is inside this handy file!